# Optional logging into a file in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a scientific computation code in C++. There are outputs that I want to write in a console and outputs that I write into a file. However, when debugging after implementing a new feature, it is useful to print out much more information than usual. So far I was just sending  more information to std::cout/clog and commented these lines out when not needed.

What I want is like std::clog, which would go into a file when needed, or not do anything at all, when not needed. It is ok, if I need to recompile the code to switch between the two regimes. It is important that nothing happens when not needed, because for a real large calculation the log file would be enormous (or the the console full of rubbish) and all the writing would slow the calculation down.

I am looking for the smallest possible implementation, ideally using only standard libraries for portability.

The obvious solution is to have a global variable, redirect clog to a file and then use an if statement.

```
bool DEBUG = true;
std::ofstream out("logfile");
std::clog.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
...
if (DEBUG) std::clog << "my message" << std::endl;
...
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

**Edit:**
I would like to avoid using non-standard libraries and preprocessor macros (program is spread across many files and also a bad programming habit in general). One way I could imagine this working, but I don't know how to do it, is to create a globally accessible object that would be able to accept messages using << and would save them to a file. Then I could just comment out the line inside this object class that saves it to a file. However, I don't know how much performance impact may result from passing messages to such a disfunctional object.

Comment: You need a logging library. Check out spdlog.

Comment: you can use if-else preprocessor

Comment: you can put `if (DEBUG) std::clog` into macro like `#define DEBUG_CLOG if (DEBUG) std::clog`, then `DEBUG_CLOG << "my message";` ... make sure the `DEBUG` variable is actually `constexpr` like `constexpr bool DEBUG = false;`, so the compiler know at compile time that the whole `if` is false and can be removed. (not sure if elegant... and macros are generally source of problems ... but in this particular case the resulting source seems reasonable to me) (or you can pass that `true/false` value at compile time as another define, i.e. `-DDEBUGLOGON=false` and do `if (DEBUGLOGON)`

Comment: btw avoid generic names as `DEBUG`, that will easily clash with something else... i.e. if you will go to the dark path of defines and preprocessor, use something distinct like `ADAMSCICO_LOG_ON=false` ...

Comment: If you already use some library like boost you can use the logger, e.g. [boost logger](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) or [poco logger](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Logger.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may use any external logging library for C/C++.
Or create your own small implementation with only utilities what you need.

A traditional logging mechanism is build on macros (or inline functions) and looks like:

```
#define LOG_MESSAGE(msg) \
{
#ifdef DEBUG
// your debug logging
#else
// your release logging, may be leaved empty
#endif // DEBUG
}
```

It's also useful to add different logging levels: Error, Warning, Info, etc.